# Mutliple IDEA instances per ONE(!) project (not just editor windows)

Tags: intellij-idea

You can have a full idea window with all the things like navigation pane, version control etc. for each project you open. That is nice.

But can I have two windows for ONE project? Thing is, sometimes you work on something on one virtual desktop and on something else on a different desktop, yet you do it in the same project.

And no, moving the tab out will not create a new IDEA window/instance, but just a IDEA EDITOR outside the full IDEA instance for that project. You would have to move back and forth from one virtual desktop to another to do something else then edit files inside IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to open the one project *twice* in IntelliJ.

But what you can do is open a second project, and open files from the first project in the second window. Of course you won't have Project Structure, navigation, or things like that, but at least you'll have an editor if that's what you want.

I presume you also know about functions "Tile Horizontally / Vertically".

You can also define shortcuts to quickly jump between files.

Comment: Well if I wanted just the editor, I would grab the tab and drag and drop it outside the ide window, which would generate an editor window. But thanks for the effort. Not sure what you mean by tile horiz/vert, but sounds irrelevant. As per shortcuts, yes - the thing is that by having a set of files opened in the instance you are having a mental context of what you are modifying in the context of the issue. Thanks for your ansewrt

Answer (score 0):

This was addressed in the Intellij IDEA support board:

> Well ... technically  you cannot open exactly the same project twice in the same IDE. The project is identified by project settings/configuration, which is normally stored in .idea subfolder. This prevents particular IDE from opening the same project twice (at the same time).
>
> What you can do here -- is some workaround, which will allow you to open the same folders/files (or whatever) in 2 different projects (which means 2 different PhpStorm windows). The general idea is here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-343
>
> What you need to do in your case (if so desired):
>
> 1. Go to anywhere where you want to keep your project settings (e.g. C:\MyProjects)
> 2. In PhpStorm create new empty project there (e.g. C:\MyProjects\PHPonly)
> 3. Go to "Settings | Directories" and detach current Content Root
> 4. Now attach new Content Root with the files of your actual project (e.g. mark unwanted folders as Excluded on the same settings page)
> 5. Repeat #2-#4 but for another folders/files (e.g. C:\MyProjects\CSSonly)
>
> In the end you will have 2 separate projects (each has it's own configuration but can work with the same source files) which you can open in separate IDE windows.

[Source](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207060065/comments/206989655)

---

The same post also addresses some workarounds like coloring or labeling the tabs, which may help with navigation. However reading your requirements, this may not be a solution in your case.